# Detect multiple tgz files in a directory with shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to use the following condition to detect *.tgz archives in a directory:

`if [ -e ${INPUT_DIRECTORY}*tgz ]`

While this condition works great when there is only one file, it's giving me an `expected binary operator` error on the 'if' line of my script, when there is more than one *.tgz file in the directory.

What am I missing ?

Comment: The description of the `-e` option in `man test` suggests that it wasn't intended to be used for multiple files.

Comment: More information would be helpful, since this smells a bit like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info). Is the lack of tgz files in that directory considered an error? Meaning, do you actually need to detect the **absence** rather than the presence of such files?

Answer (score 0):

You can just `ls` it, then check the exit code of ls. If it's 0 then the file exist, otherwise it doesn't.

```
$ ls wfh.sh
wfh.sh
$ echo $?
0
$ ls a
ls: cannot access 'a': No such file or directory
$ echo $?
2
```

In your case, you can write:

```
ls ${INPUT_DIRECTORY}*.tgz > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
  echo "exist!"
else
  echo "not!"
fi
```

Also, you should change your globbing to `${INPUT_DIRECTORY}*.tgz` instead of `${INPUT_DIRECTORY}*tgz` since it may unintentionally match something like `filletgz`

For more readable script, you can also write:

```
if ls ${INPUT_DIRECTORY}*.tgz > /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
  echo "exist!"
else
  echo "not!"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a suggestion for a test, in pure shell:

```
for i in "$input_dir"/*.tgz "$input_dir"/.*.tgz; do
    test -e "$i" && break
done
```

This returns success or failure, depending on if `.tgz` files exist. You can obviously remove the second pattern if you want to ignore hidden files.

As a function/example:

```
suffix_exists ()
{
    for i in "${2:-.}"/*"$1" "${2:-.}"/.*"$1"; do
        test -e "$i" && return 0
    done
}

if suffix_exists .tgz "$input_dir"; then
    echo "$input_dir contains .tgz archives"
else
    echo "$input_dir does not contain .tgz archives"
fi
```

It uses the current directory if none is provided.

As mentioned in another answer, you might be approaching your task in the wrong way (perhaps post your objective). Instead of detecting `.tgz` archives in the directory, you could run a command on any archives that do exist, using `find`. For example extracting them:

```
find "$input_dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \
     -type f -name '*.tgz' -exec tar xf {} \;
```

Or moving them somewhere:

```
find "$input_dir" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 \
     -type f -name '*.tgz' -exec mv -i {} /my/archives \;
```